# Web.config variable update not working with Azure DevOps pipeline (File Transform)

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-deployment, azure-pipelines-release-task

I'm trying to use the task "File Transform" within my pipeline to modify a few values inside my web.config file during deployment.

I created the tasks as the following:

[image]

And in the pipeline, inside the variables, I set up the key & value that I want to replace in the XML file.

Everything seems to go fine, however, when I check the log, I see this

[image]

So, the file was simple skipped and the transformation didn't work.

The variable that I'm trying to modify in the web.config file has the following path inside the XML file

```
  <aspNetCore>
   <environmentVariables>
     <environmentVariable  name="x" value="y" />
    </environmentVariables>
   </aspNetCore>
 </configuration>
```

I read the documentation multiples times, but it's not clear if I'm doing something wrong.

Please, could you provide some suggestion of what I need to check to make it work?

Thank you

Comment: You can try to use [replace token](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens) task or PowerShell scripts to make it work. You can refer to my samples:[replace token task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65972616/azure-devops-pipelines-for-project-and-deployment-specific-variables/65988844#65988844) and [PowerShell scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64480749/configuring-settings-in-javascript-in-azure-web-app-built-in-azure-devops/64493738#64493738)

Comment: Glad to know your issue has been resolved. Please mark your answer. This will make it easier for people who have the same question to find answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering my own question.

Based on the comments that I received, the solution that I found was the following:

1- Use Replace Token Task (https://github.com/qetza/vsts-replacetokens-task#readme) in the pipeline AFTER the deployment. I also removed that "File Transform", since it wouldn't work for what I needed.
2- In the configuration, I pointed the root folder to the deployed application, no the Zip file, as instructed by this other question ([Azure Dev ops replace tokens per environment in release pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56223728/azure-dev-ops-replace-tokens-per-environment-in-release-pipeline))
3- In the web.config file, I used the token prefix and suffix, as suggested "#{token}#
4- Added the variables to the variable groups

After deploying, I checked that it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

According to the document about [XML variable substitution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops&tabs=Classic#xml-variable-substitution):Variable substitution takes effect only on the `applicationSettings`, `appSettings`, `connectionStrings`, and `configSections` elements of configuration files. It does not apply to your `environmentVariable` element. It worked well on my side when I change value in `appSettings` element.

Please refer to the samples in the document about [file transform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops&tabs=Classic).

Comment: Indeed this documentation says that, however, the task that I tried to use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/file-transform?view=azure-devops doesn't clearly says that, so I thought that it could work with other fields. Maybe there is some room for improvement in the documentation